# putting separate Bash greps into columns?

Tags: awk

From the main directory (containing several sub-directories), I want to cd into all directories ending in *bk, and do three things:

```
$1 = ls *enp
$2 = grep "Start time" *initial.rpt
$3 = grep "Stop time" *ending.rpt
```

I would like the output to be organized with all 3 components on the same line:

```
1. Bill.enp    12:00    14:30
2. Barb.enp    15:00    15:30
3. Brad.enp    16:00    17:30
4. Buck.enp    18:00    19:00
5. Burt.enp    19:30    21:00
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you give us the input file formats this can probably be done all at once with a single awk script.

Comment: Wait... this is being done in a `perl` script and you want an `awk` solution? Not a `perl` one?

Comment: the obvious thing would be to do it in the perl script

Answer (score 1):

Using those values you want the `paste` command.

If those are in three files: `paste out1 out2 out3`

If those are in three variables: `paste <(echo "$s1") <(echo "$s2") <(echo "$s3")`

Comment: Hey Etan and others, perhaps it would be better as a single sine awk command? Specifically, this is what I'm trying for: first search: ls -d *bk second search: grep "Start" *rep_1.rpt third search: grep "Stop" *rep_1.rpt I would like to pull the last 2 pieces of info from every directory that ends with *bk and organize the 3 sets of info into columns

Comment: @user3159380 I don't think I understand exactly. You are trying to get that 3x3 output for each directory? With what contents exactly? Can you show (in the OP) some toplevel directories, some sample file names in the directories, and the output (or part of the output) for one single directory?

Comment: sorry I'm not explaining it very well, I'm still pretty new at this. In my top directory are several subdirectories (some belong to coworkers, but all directories tagged with "bk" belong to me). I want to go into each of the sub-directories with "bk at the end and do 3 things inside each of those directories: 1) list the name of the file that ends in *enp 2) grep "Start" out of a file that ends in initial.rpt and 3) grep "Stop" out of a file that ends in ending.rpt. I'll update the OP as well.

Comment: NOW, as far as the output or format goes, I want each piece of info together, with the 1)2)3) together on 1 line, and then the results of 1)2)3) for the next subdirectory on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Iff the commands

```
ls *enp
grep "Start time" *initial.rpt
grep "Stop time" *ending.rpt
```

all give place to the same number of lines and the lines are always in the proper sequence you can use the following script (credit to Etan Reisner for the original mention of [*process substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html))

```
for d in *.bk ; do
  if [ -d $d ] ; then
    cd $d
    paste -d\\t <(ls *enp) <(grep "Start time" *initial.rpt) <(grep "Stop time" *ending.rpt)
    cd -
 done
```

I have used tabs as delimiters for the `paste` command, the default is a space.

Comment: I modified this a little for perl, but it worked overall, thanks!